# Как написать алгоритм или бота на Python для эмулятора LDPlayer

Tags: python, бот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как написать бота, который из файла будет добавлять номера в контакты на эмуляторе LDPlayer один за другим, а также лишние символы из строки исключать, чтобы добавлялся чистый номер
Я не понимаю даже что нужно изучить, какая это сфера в питоне, как это вообще делать

Comment: А я не понимаю, что такое `LDPlayer`, например. Хорошо бы такие вещи прямо в вопросе пояснять.

Comment: я же написал, что это эмулятор